# Создание одного объекта из двух других

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, solid

Есть интерфейс, описывающий задание в тестовой работе

**IExercise.cs**

```
public interface IExercise
{
    int Number { get; set; } //номер задания
    int MaxValue { get; set; } //максимальный балл за задание
    ExerciseResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

его реализация

**Exercise.cs**

```
public class Exercise : IExercise
{    
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
    public ExerciseResult Result { get; set; }

    public Exercise()
    {
        Result = new ExerciseResult();
    }
}
```

и класс, который создает этот объект

**ExerciseManager.cs**

```
public class ExerciseManager
{
    public List<Exercise> GetExerciseList(IEnumerable<string> results) 
    {
        List<Exercise> exercises = new List<Exercise>();

        //здесь происходит итерация коллекции results, на основе которой 
        //создаются объекты Exercise и добавляются в результирующую коллекцию exercises

        return exercises;
    }
}
```

С созданием и работой объекта `Exercise` проблем не возникает. Поехали дальше.

Соблюдая принцип dependency inversion, создаем еще один интерфейс для работы с уже более расширенной версией `Exercise`

**IExerciseWithThemes.cs**

```
public interface IExerciseWithThemes
{
    string SubjectParts { get; set; } //разделы i.e.: 01 Механика        
    string SubjectThemes { get; set; } //Проверяемые элементы содержания (темы)
    string SubjectSkills { get; set; } //Проверяемые умения
    string Level { get; set; } //Б-П-В or "Б;П"
}
```

и его реализацию

**ExerciseWithThemes.cs**

```
public class ExerciseWithThemes : IExercise, IExerciseWithThemes, ICloneable
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; } 
    public ExerciseResult Result { get; set; }

    public string SubjectParts { get; set; }        
    public string SubjectThemes { get; set; }
    public string SubjectSkills { get; set; } 
    public string Level { get; set; } 

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new ExerciseWithThemes()
        {
            Number = this.Number,
            MaxValue = this.MaxValue,
            Result = this.Result,
            SubjectParts = this.SubjectParts,
            SubjectThemes = this.SubjectThemes,
            SubjectSkills = this.SubjectSkills,
            Level = this.Level
        };
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**

Проблема в том, что у меня **не получается правильно спроектировать класс для работы/создание объекта** `ExerciseWithThemes`. Его свойства `Number`, `MaxValue` и `Result` инициализируются **также с помощью коллекции** `IEnumerable`, а вот остальные -  `SubjectParts`, `SubjectThemes`, `SubjectSkills`, `Level` **при помощи объекта** `Excel.Range`. Т.е. в создающем классе *(ExerciseWithThemesManager)* "должно" происходить, что-то вроде:

```
foreach (Excel.Range row in rows.Rows)
{                
    exercises.Add(new ExerciseWithThemes
    {
        Number = number++,
        SubjectParts = row.Cells[1, 1].Value2.ToString(),
        SubjectThemes = row.Cells[1, 2].Value2.ToString(),
        SubjectSkills = row.Cells[1, 3].Value2.ToString(),
        Level = row.Cells[1, 4].Value2.ToString(),            
    });
}
```

Но как не продублировать код и правильно спроектировать классы? В случаи с `ExerciseManager`, думаю у меня получился паттерн `Фабричный метод`, а с *ExerciseWithThemesManager* я больше смотрю в сторону `Строитель` т.к. `ExerciseWithThemes` создается по частям c помощью двух отдельных сущностей.

Comment: Несколько концептуальных вопросов:
1) Возможно ли соотношение между IExercise и ExerciseResult один-ко-многим? Т.е. может быть много результатов по одному и тому же заданию.
2) Возможно ли соотношение между IExerciseWithThemes и IExercise (сейчас это у вас одна сущность) один-ко-многим? Т.е. в одной и той же теме может быть несколько заданий.

Comment: @Raider 1) - нет. `ExerciseResult ` пока содержит только одно поле `Percent` (% выполнения задания). 2)  Вопрос по тяжелее, может я не правильно понял или ты? `IExerciseWithThemes` это у меня тоже **задание** у которого просто больше свойств. Т.е. это **не тема**. Хотя в будущем у меня планируется ввести объект _Тема_ которое проверяет несколько заданий.

Comment: Вообще, советую рисовать UML диаграммы, чтобы понимать, какие сущности есть, и какие взаимоотношения между ними. Один из принципов ООП гласит: prefer composition over inheritance. Префиксы Subject вам намекают, что пора бы их вынести в отдельную сущность, а IExercise*With*Themes намекает, что это композиция, а не наследование.